# has_many and has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are two models:

1. **T**
2. **TGroup**

TGroup object may have many T objects.
TGroup object has one favorite T object.

I want to define associations that will provide me the following functionality:

1. `TGroup.first.ts` # will return list of T objects belong to `TGroup.first` object
2. `TGroup.first.favorite` # will return the favorite T object of the `TGroup.first` object
3. `TGroup.first.ts << T.first` # will attach T.first object to the `TGroup.first` object
4. `TGroup.first.favorite = T.first` # will set the `T.first` object as the
   favorite of `TGroup.first` object

The solution I tried to implement was:

1. Define t_group_id field (integer) on T
2. Define favorite_id field (integer) on TGroup
3. Define the following associations on TGroup model

> has_many :ts, :class_name => T.to_s
>
> has_one :t, :class_name => T.to_s, :foreign_key => :id, :primary_key => :favorite_id

I didn't succeed to define the "favorite" (should be something like ":as => :favorite"?) alias so I started with "t" instead.
Unfortunately, doing that I can't set `TGroup.first.t = T.first`. Instead of setting the `TGroup.first.t.id` to `T.first.id` it makes changes on T model.

Comment: I hate it when people call their classes stuff like "T"...

Comment: Can a TGroup be associated with more than one T?  Ie is it the case that a TGroup has many T's, and one of those is the favorite?

Comment: You definitely need to review your class and associations names.

Comment: Concerning hating the "T" name - too strong feelings :). It was just an example. Obviously in my code I don't call the classes "T", "Foo", "Bar" etc. Don't worry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you need is a belongs_to association rather than a has_one one.

According to the docs the foreign key goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association, so something like this should do the job:

```
belongs_to :favorite, :class_name => T.to_s
```

The has_one/belongs_to associations can be sometimes a bit confusing depending on each particular context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I disagree with your spelling of favorite, but I don't disagree with your answer.

Comment: Oooops, sorry about that, fixing... Although, in british english it is right, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, favourite is the british spelling, so you weren't technically wrong...  In the question, however, they used the american spelling though, so I thought I'd point it out for consistency...